# Split git repository including renamed files

Tags: git

I used to have a single repository:

```
my-project/
    app/
        common/
            logger.js
        foo/
        bar/
        index.js
```

The `logger.js` file located in `my-project/app/common` used to be located in `my-project/app`. It has been moved with `git mv`. The command `git log -- app/common/logger.js` only returns the history since it has been moved, all the history linked to its previous location has been lost. However this lost history can be accessed using `git log --follow -- app/common/logger.js`

I have split this repo into 4:

- `my-project-common`: contains `my-project/app/common`
- `my-project-foo`: contains `my-project/app/foo`
- `my-project-bar`: contains `my-project/app/bar`
- `my-project`: contains `my-project/app/index.js`

I achieved this with `git filter-branch` and it worked.

**Problem**: When moving `my-project/app/common` into `my-project-common/`, the history of `logger.js` only contains the history linked to its previous location (ie: `my-project/app/common`). The history linked to the location `my-project/app` is not accessible, even with `--follow`.

**Question**: How to preserve the full history of `logger.js`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no other way to view the history beside the `--follow` flag.

The only other way i can think of is to split the repo into 4 different repositories and then merge them back again.

---

Another way is to split the repositories to separate ones and use the pars as submodules. Again as before this solution require to split the repo.

### ***`Summary`***

The only way to see full history of removed file is to use the `git log --follow`.

The other way is to split the repository to different repositories and use each part as separate repo or to combine them back to the original repo.

#### ***`How to split repository (folders based)`***

Read this answer for full description.
[make new git branch containing full history of only some files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36184532/make-new-git-branch-containing-full-history-of-only-some-files/36185063#36185063)

Comment: Actually, the `--follow` flag does not return anything once split into the new repo.

Comment: What exactly did you do? you should have the log. if you don't you can always use `git filter-branch` once you split the branches and to move the files manually. But if you split it using the split command as explained in the answer it should work an you should see the content.

Comment: I did exactly what I said. And when thinking about it, it's normal that `git log --follow` does not show the previous location history since `--follow` is just sugar that concatenates the history of multiple files (even if these no longer exist). Though it does not solve my problem.

Comment: Ok, so you the only way is to use the `git log --follow`